# LINQ Select syntax returns all columns instead of selected ones

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I m trying to select and return certain columns from a table instead, the query ignores the selection and returns all columns in addition to related fields in related table.
How can I return only selected columns?

This my `API Controller`,

```
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/Common")]
public class CommonController : Controller
{
    private readonly ArtCoreDbContext _context;

    public CommonController(ArtCoreDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<IdState> GetState()
    {
        return _context.IdState;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetState([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        var  L2EQuery = await (from i in _context.IdState
                                      select new { Id = i.StaeId, i.text }).ToListAsync();

        return Ok(L2EQuery);
    }
}
```

**Update**

This is the model,

```
public class IdState
        {
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key]
            public int StaeId { set; get; }
            public int CouyId { set; get; }
            [Display(Name = "State"), Required]
            public string text { set; get; }
            public ICollection<PatReg> State { get; set; }
            public ICollection<IdCity> TblIdCity { get; set; }

        }
```

and the output is,

```
[{
    "staeId": 1,
    "couyId": 2,
    "text": "California",
    "state": null,
    "tblIdCity": null
}, {
    "staeId": 2,
    "couyId": 2,
    "text": "WA",
    "state": null,
    "tblIdCity": null
}, {
    "staeId": 3,
    "couyId": 1,
    "text": "Ajloun",
    "state": null,
    "tblIdCity": null
}, {
    "staeId": 4,
    "couyId": 1,
    "text": "Amman",
    "state": null,
    "tblIdCity": null
}]
```

`ajax` call

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script src="~/ArtCoreScripts/Pages/ClinicCore/PatientRegistration.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "/api/Common",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>}
```

Using LINQPad 5 I get the selected columns only,

[image: LINQPad 5 Output]

Comment: How do you see it returns more than id and text?

Comment: I m using `ajax` and output to `console`

Comment: show `IdState` class and output

Comment: show calling code

Comment: I added the calling method

Comment: you calling wrong method without parameter, updated my answer

Comment: Still getting the same output, shouldn't the parameter `id` be optional in this context? its not used for filtering data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you call method `public IEnumerable<IdState> GetState()` and it returns to you whole table.

Maybe, you need to call `Task<IActionResult> GetState([FromRoute] int id)`

Problem is here:
`url: "/api/Common",` you calling wrong method, add parameter:

`url: "/api/Common/123",`

or maybe:

```
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "/api/Common",
            data: {id: 123},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I added the routing in the question, does not get called automatically considering the routing `Task<IActionResult> GetState([FromRoute] int id)`

Comment: how can I make the parameter optional in this case, I tried `public async Task<IActionResult> GetState([FromRoute] int? id)` but did not work?

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with your C# code, but the JavaScript.

You didn't specify the action within the controller, so it defaulted to the parameter-less `HttpGet`-enabled action, which doesn't project any fields. So the problem lies within your AJAX call. Correct it like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    // Pay attention on the next line !
    url: "/api/Common/123",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

"123" is just an example, but as I can see, currently it doesn't matter because you don't filter anything in your LINQ. However, you must specify it in the URL so it could be resolved to the correct method.

Comment: Bad call, `GET https://localhost:44303/api/Common/GetStates/123 404 ()`

Comment: Routing is on `common` ( `[Route("api/Common")]`) Not `GetStates`, No?

Comment: Ooops, my bad. I mistakenly assumed the attribute on the controller is `RoutePrefix`...

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this

```
 public class CommonController : Controller
    {

        private readonly ArtCoreDbContext _context;

        public CommonController(ArtCoreDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<IdState> GetState()
        {

            return _context.IdState;
        }
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetState([FromRoute] int id)
        {
            var  L2EQuery = await (from i in _context.IdState
                                    where i.test.equals("abc")
                                      select new { Id = i.StaeId, text= i.text }).ToListAsync();

            return Ok(L2EQuery);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it does not look like an answer

Comment: Do I need to filter using `where` to the query to work?